# scopes not working in microsoft graph API

Tags: laravel, microsoft-graph-api

In my Laravel app, I am using https://github.com/dcblogdev/laravel-microsoft-graph package to Log in with M365. It was working fine till I changed the scopes in config/msgraph.php file. The default file is

```
<?PHP

return [

    /*
    * the clientId is set from the Microsoft portal to identify the application
    * https://apps.dev.microsoft.com
    */
    'clientId' => env('MSGRAPH_CLIENT_ID'),

    /*
    * set the application secret
    */

    'clientSecret' => env('MSGRAPH_SECRET_ID'),

    /*
    * Set the url to trigger the oauth process this url should call return MsGraph::connect();
    */
    'redirectUri' => env('MSGRAPH_OAUTH_URL'),

    /*
    * set the url to be redirected to once the token has been saved
    */

    'msgraphLandingUri'  => env('MSGRAPH_LANDING_URL'),

    /*
    set the tenant authorize URL
    */

    'tenantUrlAuthorize' => env('MSGRAPH_TENANT_AUTHORIZE'),

    /*
    set the tenant token URL
    */
    'tenantUrlAccessToken' => env('MSGRAPH_TENANT_TOKEN'),

    /*
    set the authorize URL
    */
    'urlAuthorize' => 'https://login.microsoftonline.com/'.env('MSGRAPH_TENANT_ID', 'common').'/oauth2/v2.0/authorize',

    /*
    set the token URL
    */
    'urlAccessToken' => 'https://login.microsoftonline.com/'.env('MSGRAPH_TENANT_ID', 'common').'/oauth2/v2.0/token',

    /*
    set the scopes to be used, Microsoft Graph API will accept up to 20 scopes
    */

    'scopes' => 'offline_access openid calendars.readwrite contacts.readwrite files.readwrite mail.readwrite mail.send tasks.readwrite mailboxsettings.readwrite user.readwrite',

    /*
    The default timezone is set to Europe/London this option allows you to set your prefered timetime
    */
    'preferTimezone' => env('MSGRAPH_PREFER_TIMEZONE', 'outlook.timezone="Europe/London"'),

    /*
    set the database connection
    */
    'dbConnection' => env('MSGRAPH_DB_CONNECTION', 'mysql'),
];
```

Where I have changed the scopes to

```
'scopes' => 'AuditLog.Read.All DeviceManagementConfiguration.Read.All DeviceManagementConfiguration.ReadWrite.All Directory.Read.All Directory.ReadWrite.All IdentityRiskyUser.Read.All Policy.Read.All RoleAssignmentSchedule.Read.Directory RoleAssignmentSchedule.ReadWrite.Directory RoleManagement.ReadWrite.Directory RoleManagement.Read.Directory RoleManagement.Read.All SecurityEvents.Read.All SecurityEvents.ReadWrite.All User.Read.All User.ReadWrite.All Exchange.ManageAsApp',
```

After changing the scopes, when I enter the proper mail and password it remains on the login page itself, not going forward.

Comment: I also think it's duo to missing `openid`, this is for sign in identity. Since you mentioned `nothing changed`, I want to double confirm with you that, have you clean and rebuild the project after changing the scope? I don't know PHP so I can't test for you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you have to add `openid` scope.

```
'scopes' => 'openid AuditLog.Read.All DeviceManagementConfiguration.Read.All DeviceManagementConfiguration.ReadWrite.All Directory.Read.All Directory.ReadWrite.All IdentityRiskyUser.Read.All Policy.Read.All RoleAssignmentSchedule.Read.Directory RoleAssignmentSchedule.ReadWrite.Directory RoleManagement.ReadWrite.Directory RoleManagement.Read.Directory RoleManagement.Read.All SecurityEvents.Read.All SecurityEvents.ReadWrite.All User.Read.All User.ReadWrite.All Exchange.ManageAsApp',
```

`openid` represents the sign-in permission. The `openid` scope can be used at the Microsoft identity platform token endpoint to acquire ID tokens. The app can use these tokens for authentication.

You also removed the `offline_access` scope. It's up to whether you add or not this scope but with the `offline_access` scope, your app can receive refresh tokens.

Comment: nothing changed after I added openid and offline_access. It gives "We couldn't sign you in. Please try again." error.

Comment: @DivyeshJesadiya Did you set the permissions also in Azure portal for the app in Azure Active Directory? Any reason you are using Exchange.ManageAsApp permission? It's not related to Graph API. Try to remove Exchange.ManageAsApp if possible.

Comment: Now I need to add Exchange.ManageAsApp in scope. How can I ask for the scope of the graph and exchange at the same time? Does it have any different flow?

Comment: @DivyeshJesadiya What I remember, Graph API and Exchange have different auth flow and you cannot generate one access token for more audiences, but I would suggest to create a new question for this, so other will know best way to help you

Comment: Okay. I have asked it here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77583488/could-not-use-graph-api-and-exchange-scope-in-one-auth-flow-of-microsoft-graph-a